# Google Analytics API for user explorer

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Google Analytics is rolling out a new feature called User Explorer that offers website administrators a chance to see a specific visitor interactions across my website. The timestamp of each activity is shown on the google analytics official user interface.

Is there any related API to get the data?

---

I have looking for the relative topic "google analytics api individual history".

However, get nothing.

Comment: The fact that the clientid is not listed in the metrics and dimensions reference, and that it's not exposed in the interface as dimension (for filters and segments) seems to indicate that you cannot query this via the API.

Comment: Well, you can't request direct by clientId but you can use a custom dimension set to the user's clientId and go from there